# Cannot fetch from or insert data to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose

I wrote a node web app and created a mongoDb database on my local system. I was using the following code to connect to local mongodb from node js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_name'); //local
```

And everything was working fine on my local machine. So I went on and created an mlab account and created a database. But when I tried to run the code by changing the connection string, connections are still established I believe. But the find and save requests are not invoking the callbacks, even no errors shows up. All requests are getting timed out.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:pass@ds036789.mlab.com:36789/db_name"); //mlab
```

Another thing I noticed is that I cannot ping ds036789.mlab.com. But TCP connections are succeeding when I tried the nc command

```
nc -w 3 -v ds036789.mlab.com 36789
```

I even tried deploying to azure. Which doesn't work either. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
Not being able to ping was due to the fact that I used azure hosting. It is expected. And I also found out that I get this error while trying to connect :

```
connection error: { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

Credentials are correct though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, it wasn't an issue with the credentials. It was an issue with the mongoose version. The mongoose version I used didn't support the authentication. I had to remove the package and reinstall the latest version. with

```
node install mongoose@latest
```

Hope it helps someone. And thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

From the error mesasge it seems like you are using invalid auth details

This is most likely happen when you do not create username and password for `individual database` i.e, `db_name` in you case.

Check mLabs account and create username and password for `db_name` database and update your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error information, as @Astro said, it seems to be caused by using invalid auth `user/password` which be created for database.

Did you create a new user for connecting the database, not account user for mlab? Such as the figures below shown.

Fig 1. A database user is required for connecting
[image]

Fig 2. Users list for the database
[image]

Hope it helps.